# How to use zend_http_client or curl in right way

Tags: php, zend-framework, rest, curl, zend-http-client

I'm using zend_http_client. What i want is to send a request to transfer(without redirecting) to another site and send number in field that I have and get the answer with info i need to use on my site. That's what i'm doing, but how to send my number to that field and submit it?

```
 $url = 'http://gdeposylka.ru/';
                        $config = array(
                            'timeout' => 30
                        );
                        $client = new Zend_Http_Client($url, $config);
                        try {
                            $response = $client->request('GET');
                            if ($response->getStatus() == 200) {
                                $ctype = $response->getHeader('Content-type');
                                $body = $response->getBody();
                                $dom = new Zend_Dom_Query($body);
                                $results = $dom->query('limit');
                                $item->site_k = 1 + (int) $results->current()->textContent;
                                var_dump($response);
                                exit;
                            }
                        } catch (Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Exception $e) {

                        }
```

Thanks and sorry for grammar mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is a hash on the site you're trying to send a request, you probably wont be able to get this done. Hash mechanism makes it impossible to send request straight to the URL stated in `action` param of `form` tag. It's designed particulary to prevent such action you want to make. Still, since there is no captcha you can try web automation.

What you might find useful is ie. Selenium http://docs.seleniumhq.org/

Comment: what about this sites http://www.track-trace.com/post or http://www.emspost.ru/ru/corp_clients/dogovor_docements/api/

Comment: I cannot read cyryllic but on the second site I see there is some API, which should be quite useful. You can get JSON very easly with `file_get_contents('http://emspost.ru/api/rest?method=ems.test.echo')` (mind that this function might be turned off on your server with `allow_url_fopen` flag).

Comment: I'm afraid there is no function to get package status in the API you have mentioned. Just general info and shipping cost calculations.

Comment: i think i find what i need, it's http://www.trackchecker.ru/tracking/?RA123456789RU, but how can i get info back on my site?

Comment: Obviously, you need to parse the site. You can use some library to ease that task (like http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @Stopper, there is another problem - that site is also protected from such simple HTML reading with AJAX request which is done after page is loaded. You can try accessing that URL (http://www.trackchecker.ru/tracking/dotrack.php?tn=RA123456789RU&_=1368446179040) but as you can see it's also protected :)